# Relearning Linear Algebra after 2 years away from it. Confused about some concepts.

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

I took linear algebra during the COVID era and I did really well and really enjoyed it, but then again it was the COVID era. So I recently bought the Axler book on Linear Algebra, but while I am reading thought it, I notice the text references the jth coordinate, term, slot, etc. and I was just confused by what the significance of this might be? I've been looking through the book to see if there was something I possibly missed and I can't seem to find anything, nor is there really anything online about it.

Just curious if it is something that I need to emphasize while I relearn this content? or is it something analytically nuanced that can be omitted for the sake of relearning the techniques?

Thanks!

edit: I will quote a specific section for reference:

"Suppose $U_j$ is the subspace for $F^n$ of those vectors whose coordinates are all $0$, except possible the $j^{th}$ slot..."

or

" $F^n$ is the set of all lists of length *n* of elements of **F**:

$F^n = [({x_1},...,{x_n}): {x_j} \epsilon \ for \ j =  1,...,n]$
for $({x_1}, ... , {x_n})\ \epsilon\ {F^n}\ and\ j\ \epsilon\ [1,...,n],$
we say that ${x_j}$ is the $j^{th}$ coordinate of $({x_1},...,{x_n})$ "

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! It's a bit hard to tell what you're confused about, can you explictly reference a passage from the book where something you don't understand appears ? See also [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: First of all, understand how to solve a linear system of n equations with m unknowns, 1) first with $m=n$, for example $m=n=2$ or $m=n=3$, 2) then in the case $n<m$, for example with $n=2$ and $m=3$ (where the idea is to consider the third coordinate $z$ as a parameter, and obtain solutions  $x=a+bz, y=c+dz$ which is an affine subspace). 3) then with the last case $n>m$ where there are in general no solution, except when the $n$ equations are compatible, etc.

Comment: Apologies. I am still learning how to ask questions properly on these kinds of forums. Thank you for your patience/ input. I will edit with references to the Text

Comment: I think your problem is with the general "n" instead of having a book which begins by working with $n=2$ or $n=3$ coordinates. I advise you for that the book of Strang : "Linear algebra" which is very progressive.

Comment: Your second quote defines what the $j$th coordinate of a vector is. If that does not answer your question then I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'm just asking if there is any real significance to the term, or if it is just some arbitrary index term. I'm fairly new to the more discrete side of things and unfortunately I tend to hyper-focus on unnecessary details if they're not 100% obvious. Just looking for some clarity

Comment: In the notation $(a,b)$, order matters. If that notation references a point in the plane, $a$ is the $x$-coordinate, and $b$ is the $y$-coordinate. $(a,b)$ is not (in general) the same as $(b,a)$. So we call $a$ the first coordinate, and $b$ the second. Nothing arbitrary about it, and it is of real significance.

Comment: Did that help??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.

Comment: Sorry, been busy. So then the author is just trying to draw attention to the ordering that is present in these lists? as a means of drawing attention to axiomatic details of things like (a,b) is not the same as (b,a)?

Comment: The author is trying to have an unambiguous way of referring to a particular entry in an ordered $n$-tuple of elements of $F$. He/she wants to be able to refer the $17$ in $(7,17,42,0)$ by saying "the second entry" and have you know exactly what is meant by that.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you all!